# Splitting polygons at narrowest part using R?

Tags: r, polygon, splitting

I have a dataset of polygons like this one:

[image]

I would like to split these polygons in separate parts at their most narrow location (if they have one). For example the two small polygons should not be split. So I would need to identify narrow locations and then split the polygon there.

How could this be done using R?

Comment: Why shouldn't the two smaller polygons be split? They must have a narrowest point if they have any variable width at all. The one lower right looks like its narrowest would cut off the left-most "blob".

Comment: But the small polygon have a narrowest part, how did you determine that they should not split (minimum area, narrowest part smaller than X, other....)

Comment: That's true – maybe some sort of polygon complexity and a size criterion should determine wether a polygon is split or not.

Comment: Sure, but if you didn't know your own requirement how could we propose a solution ?

Comment: One algorithm might be to find the smallest negative distance (ie internal) buffer that splits the polygon into two polygons, and then somehow use that to decide where to split the polygon. I've not fully worked this out yet...

Comment: If you wish to ask about how to do this using software other than R, then please do that in separate questions.

Comment: I think the first step is to clearly define what makes a successful split, which appears to me to include the smallest maximum area polygon as well as the narrowest point. If performance is not an issue, it could be brute forced by trying all possible splits.

Comment: Once you have the criteria clearly defined, you can divide and conquer by trying every nth vertex, say 20th. Try all possible splits with the other nth vertices. You can now order by tangent length and prune the shortest 10 or so. This gives you upper and lower limits to check in more detail. Find the shortest among those limits, and you have what is most likely the global minimum slice in that polygon. Now compare polygons for least maximum area (or whatever the criteria may be).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given a polygon `pol`, like this:

[image]

then:

```
> library(sf)
> sdist = -0.055168
> ppol = splitnarrow(pol, sdist, 1e-3)
> plot(ppol, col=1:2)
```

produces this:

[image]

Here's the source code for `splitnarrow`. There's a zillion places where this can go wrong, and first you have to determine `sdist` and `eps` for your polygons.

```
splitnarrow <- function(pol, sdist, eps){
###
### split a polygon at its narrowest point.
###

### sdist is the smallest value for internal buffering that splits the
### polygon into a MULTIPOLYGON and needs computing before running this.

### eps is another tolerance that is needed to get the points at which the
### narrowest point is to be cut.

    ## split the polygon into two separate polygons
    bparts = st_buffer(pol, sdist)
    features = st_cast(st_sfc(bparts), "POLYGON")

    ## find where the two separate polygons are closest, this is where
    ## the internal buffering pinched off into two polygons.

    pinch = st_nearest_points(features[1],features[2])

    ## buffering the pinch point by a slightly larger buffer length should intersect with
    ## the polygon at the narrow point. 
    inter = st_intersection(
        st_cast(pol,"MULTILINESTRING"),
        st_buffer(pinch,-(sdist-(eps))
                  )
    )
    join = st_cast(st_sfc(inter), "LINESTRING")

    ## join is now two small line segments of the polygon across the "waist".
    ## find the line of closest approach of them:
    splitline = st_nearest_points(join[1], join[2])

    ## that's our cut line. Now put that with the polygon and make new polygons:
    mm = st_union(splitline, st_cast(pol, "LINESTRING"))
    parts = st_collection_extract(st_polygonize(mm))
    parts
}
```

`sdist` is the smallest value that splits the single polygon into a multipolygon, and `eps` is the smallest value that touches both sides when buffered from the waist intersection point. Finding these could be automated.

Comment: OK, interesting – but I get an error:  Error in vapply(lst, class, rep(NA_character_, 3)) : 
  values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 4

Comment: I cant reproduce this without your polygon and the parameters you used. As I said, theres a lot of ways this can fail if presented with an unexpected structure or wildly wrong parameters.

Comment: I tested it with this GEOJSON: http://www.filedropper.com/narrow and imported it via `pol= read_sf("narrow.geojson")`. It is the feature from the question.

Comment: You have to run on the geometry object and get the buffer size and eps correct. Some trial and error gets this: `ppol = splitnarrow(pol$geometry, -17.75, eps=.1)`
 which works.

Comment: Wow, this is impressive! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your strategy in defining `sdist` and `eps`?

Comment: For `sdist`, `class(st_buffer(pol$geometry, sdist))` should be the smallest value that returns a MULTIPOLYGON - this tells you it is just big enough to pinch the polygon into two polygon at the narrowest point. Plot some negative width buffers to get an idea of how it is going. There's a similar process for `eps` but its not so critical and I haven't exactly worked out what yet...

Answer (score 5):

This would take you rather far afield, 
but one way to define the most narrow waist
of a shape is to identify the event at which the 
[straight skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton) partitions
the shrinking shape into two pieces.

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image from [here](http://student.ulb.ac.be/~dtimmerm/straightskeleton/straight-skeleton.html) (and probably copied from elsewhere).</sup>

---

You can view the polygon boundary edges moving inward at a fixed 
rate—a type of inward offset.
A narrow neck will pinch off the shape into two pieces. In the
above image, this happens a bit beyond t=4.